# Why doesn't strcmp recognize two seemingly equal strings as the same?

Tags: matlab, strcmp

Below is the output from the Matlab's console. Both of the strings are the same: `'@TBMA3'`. Yet Matlab's `strcmp` function returns `0` when comparing them. Why?

```
K>> str='@TBMA3'
str =
@TBMA3

K>> method.fhandle
ans = 
@TBMA3

K>> strcmp(method.fhandle, str)
ans =
     0
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The most likely reason is that `method.fhandle` is not a string, but a function handle. Check if `class(method.fhandle)` gives

```
ans =
function_handle
```

In that case, the comparison gives `0` because a string (`str`) cannot be equal to a function handle (`method.fhandle`).

In order to check for equality, you would need to convert `method.fhandle` to a string, or `str` to a function handle. The first option is not adequate, because `char(function_handle)` would give `'TBMS3'`, without `'@'`. So use the second option, and compare using [`isequal`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/fixedpoint/ref/isequal.html):

```
isequal(method.fhandle, str2func(str))
```

should give `1`.<sup>†</sup>

<sup><sup>†</sup> This `isequal` comparison works because both `method.fhandle` and `str2func(str)` point to the same already-defined function `TBMA3`. Compare with `f = @(x)x; g = @(x)x, isequal(f,g)`, which gives `0`. This behaviour is [explained in the documentation](https://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/compare-function-handles.html#d119e32560). Thanks to @knedlsepp for helping clarify this.</sup>

Comment: To compare you could do:  `strcmp ( func2str(method.fhandle), 'TBMA3' )`.  The other _possibility_ is that one of the strings has whitespace after it...

Comment: @matlabgui Thanks. I was precisely editing my answer in that regard. But you would need to remove the `'@`' from `str`. I think it's better the other way around: convert `str` to a function handle (and then compare with `isequal`; see edited answer)

Comment: @LuisMendo: I don't think you can compare function handles for equality 'by value'. `isequal(@(x) x, @(x) x)` fails for me. Edit: Hm, ok if it's an m.file this might work, as the handle is compared as reference. Point taken.

Comment: @knedlsepp `@(x) x` is not a function handle, but an anonymous function. It works with function handles in this case: `f = @cos; g = @cos, isequal(f,g)`. Strangely, it doesn't work in this case: `f = @(x) x; g = @(x) x, isequal(f,g)`

Comment: @knedlsepp I see your edited comment now. Does it make sense to you that the comparison works for `f = @cos` but not for `f = @(x) x`?

Comment: @LuisMendo: In this case `f` and `g` are both function handles pointing to different anonymous functions. `f = @(x) x` is equal to `g` defined by `g = f` as both point to the same anonymous function. But it doesn't really matter here I guess. I suppose the OP wants to use the function handles with handles to m-files anyway.

Comment: @knedlsepp Got it. `f = @cos; g = @cos` point to the same (already defined) function, whereas `f = @(x) x` and `g = @(x) x` don't

Comment: Absolutely. But as OP probably wants to compare some non-anonymous functions, so not converting to string is certainly the best way!

Comment: @knedlsepp I've added a footnote to clarify this (with due credit)

Comment: @knedlsepp It turns out this is explained in the documentation: http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/advanced-operations-on-function-handles.html#brlptk1-4

Comment: There are simple examples why they probably gave up implementing a real `isequal` for anonymous functions: `sin=@(x)(sin);
sin2=@(x)(sin)` These functions are not equal.

Comment: @Daniel Yes, the doc recognises that "_MATLAB may underestimate the equality of function handles. That is, a test for equality may return false even when the functions happen to behave the same_". So this is seen as a failure of `isequal`, not as intended behaviour. For objects, `isequal` tests "_if objects have equal property values, even if those objects are different handles_". This rule is simply broken with function handles